# How did Rogers happen upon Abe after he killed the courier?

Tags: plot-explanation, turn

Turn Season 2, Episode 10... Abe sets out to kill the courier that was giving his spy notes from Hewlitt to John Andre.

It was probably close to their village but I don't get why Rogers just happened upon the EXACT spot or I am missing a plot branch.   So Rogers was basically on top of Abe while Abe was killing the courier - he had him tackled in seconds.

Meaning Rogers wasn't a mile away and heard a gun shot and tracked him down.   So I am assuming that Rogers is following Abe or this is just the best bit of luck (unlucky for Abe) in the world.   Why would Rogers be following Abe out of all the things Rogers could be doing?

Also I went back and watched it again and Rogers tone with Abe was more around he was surprised to see Abe do that but had a sneaky suspicion Abe was hiding something.

Answer (score 1):

Going through the previous shows it just seems that this was TV fate.   Rogers was going back to Setauket because he felt there was something fishy going on there.  But his radar was never for Abe.

There could have been a theory that Abe was "working" for Rogers after the killing of the previous spy in town so maybe... Rogers was seeking out Abe to contact to see if he had dug up any dirt since they last saw.

This theory doesn't hold too well though because why would Rogers follow him to his dad's house then to the killing point?   If I am Rogers I would have nabbed Abe to talk to after leaving his dad's place for sure.    So this theory is plausible but highly unlikely.

It seems that the show just wants us to believe that Rogers is basically a superhero and with his blood hound nose smelled a killing that was going to happen and made his was to the road to New York.